# Terminal display problem

Tags: command-line

I've got an annoying problem with my terminal. The problem existed with the gnome terminal and even though i've got the terminator terminal as a default the problem persists!

When a code line is too long the code instead of continuing to the line below as normal it goes write back from the left of the line some times making the allready typed code invisible!

Some other times it even goes upwards!

Why is that?